# How to change text in Xcode document via AppleScript

Tags: applescript, xcode

I'm currently working on an AppleScript to invoke ClangFormat while in Xcode 11.5.

Here's the work-in-progress:

```
set fpath to ""
set selRange to {}

tell application "Xcode"
    try
        set last_word_in_main_window to (word -1 of (get name of window 1))
        if (last_word_in_main_window is "Edited") then
            display notification "Please save the current document and try again."
        else
            set doc to document 1 whose name ends with last_word_in_main_window
            set fpath to path of doc
            set selRange to the selected paragraph range of doc
            set fpath to path of doc
            set qpath to quoted form of fpath
        end if
    on error errMsg
    end try
end tell
if (count of selRange) > 0 then
    set selStart to item 1 of selRange
    set selEnd to item 2 of selRange
    do shell script "~/clang-format -lines=" & selStart & ":" & selEnd & " " & qpath & " > ~/tmp-clang-format"
    do shell script "mv ~/tmp-clang-format " & qpath
    tell application "Xcode"
        set selected paragraph range of doc to selRange
    end tell
end if
```

(The technique for getting the frontmost source document is a bit goofy; I found it on Stack Overflow and it seems to work well in practice, but obviously it's playing a bit fast and loose.)

To paraphrase, the script invokes `clang-format` and routes its output to a temp file, then uses `mv` to replace the current Xcode document with `clang-format`'s output.

This actually works better than you might expect--it updates after only a minor delay, and pretty seamlessly--but it has one flaw that stands out. You can't undo its results. Xcode just beeps if you try. Apparently file replacement is a one-way trip.

Is there a cleaner way to swap in the new file contents that would allow Undo to work? I've tried `set text of source document` to replace the doc text without actually swapping out the file, but this causes Xcode to immediately quit, so presumably that's broken in Xcode 11.5.

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/XcodeClangFormat

Comment: Does XcodeClangFormat support undoing its changes? I tried it briefly but ended up abandoning it because it had some fatal flaw, but I'm not 100% sure I recall what was wrong with it.

Comment: it was updated in late June and has been working great for me. Just remember to choose the correct file in the Xcode file navigator. And yes, it supports undoing changes. It is a macOS extension, not AppleScript.

Comment: Wow, it works great! Thanks for the tip! I'm not sure why I jettisoned it the first time but they must have improved it since I last tried it (April).